Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function. SQL
I have this code in my View on a sql database
RIGHT([Site].Site, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE([Site].Site)) - 2) AS [Project Code] 

and it's causing this error as there are some entries that would make it invalid - fine.
Msg 536, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

BUT I entirely comment out the code in the Alter view mode where it originates and can see there it's nowhere else in related sub queries or contained in the Group By clause or anywhere else in the code.
--,RIGHT([Site].Site, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE([Site].Site)) - 2) AS [Project Code]

But still get the same error when I rerun it. Why do I get this error if it's no longer part of the View and how do I fix it? We made changes to front end values of this field and know that's the cause of it falling over.

Are you saying that you commented out that calculation in your view, but you are still receiving an error about the right function? If so, then clearly there is another calculation using that function in the view, or in a different view being referenced in this one.

This is right Andrew. Yeah, but I cannot see it used anywhere else (or RIGHT function for that matter) and it's a field we've made changes to and was expecting it to throw it out. I have refreshed view and can see its no longer a column, but still get error.

Is this view being used inside another view or procedure? Did you run sp_refreshsqlmodule on that.

"sql database" may be meaningful to you, but "Microsoft SQL Server" is NOT "sql"! Hover over the tag "sql" and read those instructions.

tip: add the characters you need to find at the end of the source string so that charindex does not return zero. see: https://dbfiddle.uk/df1o6r32

There was a term used in sub sub sub View deep down and located. Thanks for the help, my bad.
